# text_field_tag with pre-filled text and custom params

Tags: view, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to get this to work in one of my views:

```
<%= text_field_tag :sources, "Test", params[:sources] %>
```

but I get undefined method 'stringify_keys' for nil:NilClass.  The code

```
<%= text_field_tag :sources, "Test" %>
```

works fine and pre-fills the box with "Test" (but doesn't pass params properly), while the the code

```
<%= text_field_tag :sources, params[:sources] %>
```

passes params properly but doesn't have the text "Test" where I need it.

Does anyone know the syntax or a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is [documented](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag):

> **text_area_tag**(name, content = nil, options = {})

The problem with your code is that given three arguments `text_field_tag` expects the third to be a Hash, but `params[:sources]` is giving `nil`. Are you expecting it to hold a different value? Where is `params` set, and what does it contain?

If you know that `params[:sources]` will sometimes contain a Hash and other times be `nil` (i.e. not set) then you could use e.g.:

```
<%= text_field_tag :sources, "Test", params[:sources] || {} %>
```

`params[:sources] || {}` will evaluate to an empty Hash (`{}`) whenever `params[:sources]` is falsy (e.g. `nil`), which will avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't passing in params as you suggested.  I set it in the controller first then displayed the view as <%= text_field_tag :sources, "Test", params %> and it works great